# Changing cases,reversing and mirror a string javascript codewars kata

Tags: javascript

Hi I have this kata problem I am currently solving the instruction of the kata are as follows:

> -Given 2 string parameters, show a concatenation of:
>
> --the reverse of the 2nd string with inverted case; e.g Fish -> HSIf
>
> --a separator in between both strings: @@@
>
> --the 1st string reversed with inverted case and then mirrored; e.g Water -> RETAwwATER

My problem is that my output have duplicate of anything that is not an alphabet for example if my input is "123" it returns "112233" please check  part of my code here which i think is giving problems, I need to find a way not to repeat adding anything that is not an alphabet on my result. For example if i input this: console.log(mirror("This cODe is ","GivIng Me 123 ProBleMS")). I get this: smELbORp 332211 Em GNiVIg@@@SIEdoCSIHttHIS CodE IS. But I want this:smELbORp 321 Em GNiVIg@@@SIEdoCSIHttHIS CodE IS

```
for (let i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    if (s1[i] == s1[i].toUpperCase()) {
        if (s1[i])
            y += s1[i].toLowerCase();
    } 

    if (s1[i] == s1[i].toLowerCase()) {
        y += s1[i].toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the link to kata..

Comment: Please attach `>what is the input` then `>what is your output` and `>what is the expected output`

Comment: Numbers are themselves if converted to uppercase. Look at your code: you have two separate `if` statements; you will always add things that are the same after conversion to the string. (And what's the point if the `if (s1[i])` statement?)

Comment: Side note: I **strongly** recommend always using blocks on control flow statements, even if you only have a single statement. (This is re the nested `if`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i'm not clear about the `--a separator in between both strings: @@@` How should it append to the final output? Should the final output is something like this `HSIf@@@RETAwwATER`

Comment: @SifatHaque - I see what you mean! :-) The OP's edited to clarify, though I think the question is more contained than the overall kata.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i think the OP's troubling in logic. I've shared my code and some suggestion. Hope that may help.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that my output have duplicate of anything that is not an alphabet for example if my input is "123" it returns "112233"

The problem is that when you're dealing with a non-alphabetic character like `"1"`, it will always be equal to both the result of `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` because they don't change those characters:

```js
console.log("1" == "1".toUpperCase()); // true
console.log("1" == "1".toLowerCase()); // also true
```

So both of your `if` conditions is true, and you append the character twice.

You probably want to use `else`, not only before the second `if` but also for a third block where you take the character just as it is (I can't immediately think of a string that wouldn't be equal to either its own `toUpperCase` or `toLowerCase`, but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist). You also don't need that nested `if`. So:

```
if (s1[i] == s1[i].toUpperCase()) {
    y += s1[i].toLowerCase();
} else if (s1[i] == s1[i].toLowerCase()) {
    y += s1[i].toUpperCase();
} else {
    y += s1[i];
}
```

The `else` branch is only followed if the `if` condition is false.

---

Side note: Since you're using ES2015+ syntax (`let`, for instance), you might consider using `for-of` for your loop:

```
for (const ch of s1) {
    if (ch == ch.toUpperCase()) {
        y += ch.toLowerCase();
    } else if (ch == ch.toLowerCase()) {
        y += ch.toUpperCase();
    } else {
        y += ch;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously, this is just one part of the kata, but it's the part you asked about and it wouldn't be appropriate to go further and solve the whole thing in this answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to do this for letters use some check like below before applying the logic:

```
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
   if(inputtxt.value.match(letters)){
     // do the logic here
      }
    else{
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just find the kata. Here is the [kata link](https://www.codewars.com/kata/string-reversing-changing-case-etc/javascript)

I think you are facing some trouble to figuring out how to change between lowerCase to upperCase or vice versa. You can just follow the following instruction.

1. check if the character is lowecase or not. If lowercase then turn that into uppercase
2. If not lowerCase then it must be upperCase or anyting else. Just turn that into lowerCase no matter what it is. Since turning anything to lowerCase except the alphabet won't work. So, that won't harm.
3. I think now you can handle the rest.

If still you are facing trouble then you can check my solution and get some insight that how it works but i would suggest that you need to try enough before viewing the solution.

```js
const changeStr = (str, reverse = false) => {
    let changedStr = str.split('').reduce((newStr, char) => {
        if(char.toLowerCase() == char) {
            return newStr += char.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            return newStr += char.toLowerCase();
        }
    }, '')
    if(reverse) changedStr = changedStr.split('').reverse().join("");
    return changedStr;
}
const concat = (str1, str2) => {
    return `${changeStr(str2, true)}@@@${changeStr(str1, true)}${changeStr(str1)}`; 
}

console.log(concat('FizZ', 'buZZ')) // zzUB@@@zZIffIZz
```